# understanding android LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() minDistance criteria

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have read up quite a few posts here on the minDistance parameter, like - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440918/understanding-requestlocationupdates-mindistance-parameter) and I do understand that minDistance onLocationChanged() is called only when the distance changes by a minimum specified by minDistance and if the time interval changes by a minimum as specified by minTime.

But what I am wondering is how is the minDistance measured ? are there events that are trigerred when the geoFence is exited ? Or is there some other mechanism ?